# Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531), Error occurs even though I am checking that in the if condition

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object, null, eslint

```
if (document.getElementById(`${element.id}-element`)) {
    document.getElementById(`${element.id}-element`).onmousedown =   // *document.getElementById(`${element.id}-element`)* gives me object is possibly null error                                                              
     dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    element.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }
```

So I tried the non-null assertion

```
if (document.getElementById(`${element.id}-element`)) {
    document.getElementById(`${element.id}-element`)!.onmousedown =
      dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    element.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }
```

But this gives me *Forbidden non-null assertion  @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion*. Is there any other approach to avoid the object possibly null error?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of repeating the expression, store it into a variable.

```
const element2 = document.getElementById(`${element.id}-element`);
if (element2) {
    element2.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
} else {
    element.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
}
```

Even better, use nullish coalescing and get rid of the if-else block.

```
const element2 = document.getElementById(`${element.id}-element`) ?? element;
element2.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
```